# Do I need to explicitly return the value in `Ok` variant of `Result` while using `?` operator?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In rust we know that `?` operator works like `match` expression. If the Result is `Ok` then the result in `Ok` variant is returned from this expression and if the Result is Err then the result in Err variant is returned from this expression and quits the function immediately. So now in this code:

```
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {

    use std::fs::File;
    use std::io::{self, Read};

    fn propagated_error() -> Result<String, io::Error> {

        let mut file = File::open("hello.txt")?;
        let mut data = String::new();
        file.read_to_string(&mut data)?;
        Ok(data)
    }

    let data = propagated_error();
    match data{
        Ok(data) => println!("{data}"),
        Err(err) => panic!("{err}")
    }

}
```

If I don't return the `Ok(data)` explicitly like that it was giving error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:119:30
    |
119 |     fn propagated_error() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    |        ----------------      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Result<String, Error>`, found `()`
    |        |
    |        implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression
    |
    = note:   expected enum `Result<String, std::io::Error>`
            found unit type `()`
```

Why???? As `?` operator works, `?` automatically returns the value in `Ok` variant, So why I had to explicitly return the value like this: `Ok(data)`???

Please help me to clear the idea.

Comment: You should show the code that failed, not the working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said yourself, you have to explicitly return an `Ok(T)` variant. And the reason for that is simple. `Result<T, E>` is a different **type** than `T`. It has a semantic meaning of a result of some operation, but to the compiler it is just an enum. You could even design one yourself:

```rust
enum MyResult<T, E> {
    Ok(T),
    Err(E),
}
```

So when you say that your function returns `Result<T, E>` you cannot just return `T`, because the types don't match.

The question mark operator is a shortcut to propagate **error** variants. You could thing about is like it is a macro (in reality it uses an unstable [Try](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait, but this mechanism is not important to understand here), that expands following code:

```rust
let x = foo()?;
```

into

```rust
let x = match foo() {
    Ok(x) => x,
    Err(e) => return Err(e.into()),
};
```

However it does not return data in `Ok` variant, as you stated before.

To summarize. You can use `?` to early return `Err` variant from function, but you need to explicitly wrap your "success" value in `Ok` variant, so that types match.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `?` operator is basically equivalent to:

```
match value {
    Ok(t) => t,
    Err(e) => return Err(e.into()),
}
```

It doesn’t just return the error if `value` is one, but also removes the `Ok` wrapper if `value` is not an error. This means it turns `Result<T, _>` into `T`, and so:

```
fn proof() -> Result<(), String> {
    Ok(())?
}
```

turns (roughly) into:

```
fn proof() -> Result<(), String> {
    match Ok(()) {
        Ok(t) => t,
        Err(e) => return Err(e.into),
    }
}
```

The result of that match is a value of type `()` but the function expects `Result<(), String>`, so you have to wrap it in `Ok`

```
fn proof() -> Result<(), String> {
    Ok(Ok(())?)
}
```

Now that looks really weird, so lets swap the inner `Ok` with a fallible function with the type `Fn() -> Result<(), &'static str>`.

```
fn proof() -> Result<(), String> {
    Ok(fallible_func()?)
}
```

Now hopefully it’s a little clearer that `?` converts and returns an error if there is one, and gives the value of `T` if there isn’t.